# Alternative backup for a huge files or folder

Tags: windows-7, backup

I am trying to figure it out how to backup a file that is 635 GB File Geodatabase.

[Backup alternative](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85534/alternative-backup-file-or-personal-geodatabase)

What I would like to try and compress the file and backup to external hard drive and save it as a new file? Is that possible?

I like the one with Create a batch in Windows 7 but I wanted to see if there is a good method to a different one?

Comment: Are you sure you mean 635GB and not 635MB?  Also, this is dangerously close to a cross post, which is a SE no-no.

Comment: Just copy the file to a 1TB file or a 1GB flash drive what ever works

Comment: Keltari no I am not mistake. It is an actually 635 GB. It is a raster I use for my work. What do you mean cross post ?

Comment: He means you already posted a duplicate question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85534/alternative-backup-file-or-personal-geodatabase)

Comment: CIA  - Thanks ! ok was trying to explaining what i was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a several options:

1) you can use the [Windows 7 native backup feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-change-automatic-backup-settings#1TC=windows-7) (this will backup your whole system);

2) you can manually right-click the file and zip it, then drag and drop the zipped file in a desired location

3) create a batch script to zip your database, then copy the file to an alternate location.  You can [use 7zip to zip your files](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Multiple-Compressed-Folders-in-One-Go) if you don't have a zip preference. Then you can create a batch file [using xcopy to copy your file to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986505/2014613).  If you're concerned about running out of space, then you can create a batch script [using forfiles to delete a file after N number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069/2014613)

4) you can invest in a backup application, like [Cobain Backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm)

Comment: CIA - Thanks for the tip. The computer has two hard drive in it and it has C drive and E drive. The E drive is almost closer to max and I think if I zip it it probably would not completed it. The E Drive free space is about 300 GB left and don't think there is enough space. I can do what you just describe it but save to external hard drive.

Comment: Depending on the geodata you're working with, you may not get a good compression ratio.  In that case, you're probably better off dumping your database to an online database as a backup procedure.

Comment: CIA  - Yeah that is the first step I am trying to find a way to back it up but if my options are out of my hands then I would have to dump it. I may need to try and do a different extension file like jpg or jpeg2000.

Comment: You can't give a file a new extension to save space. It doesn't work that way. An application has to "chomp" it to bits and create a smaller version of the file. Also, you shouldn't mess with a database file unless you know what you're doing, or else you'll break the file and it will haunt you if you try to restore it.